# How to map part of a column value with a dict in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data which looks like below

```
data = [(datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 18, 48, 18, 97962), u'London', u'New York', u'UPLOAD_LOW'), (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 18, 48, 18, 97962), u'Berlin', u'Tokyo', u'DOWNLOAD_HIGH'), (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 18, 47, 8, 209495), u'Paris', u'Toronto', u'DROP_LOW')]
```

This is how it looks when loaded in pandas

```
                        date  source destination          issue
0 2021-02-06 18:48:18.097962  London    New York     UPLOAD_LOW
1 2021-02-06 18:48:18.097962  Berlin       Tokyo  DOWNLOAD_HIGH
2 2021-02-06 18:47:08.209495   Paris     Toronto       DROP_LOW
```

Now I want to map the values in column `issue` to a dictionary. Using pandas `map` function [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map) helps get the job done. But the problem is the keys in the dictionary to be mapped against only contains a part of the column value.

Here is my dictionary below

```
issue_short_form_map = {
        "UPLOAD": "UP",
        "MEMORY": "MEM",
        "DOWNLOAD": "DN"
}
```

Now say I want to map column `issue` with the above dictionary. Usually this is what I do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ["date", "source", "destination", "issue"]
# map the values in issue column to the dictionary. Anything that doesn't match, keep the original
df["issue"] = df["issue"].map(issue_short_form_map).fillna(df["issue"])
```

But the problem is the values in `issue` column doesn't directly match with the key but only a part of it does (after splitting `_` and getting the first part).

Is there any way where doing a split on `_` on column values and mapping it with dictionary can be made to work? Anything that doesn't match should be kept as is.

My final output should look like below

```
                        date  source destination          issue
0 2021-02-06 18:48:18.097962  London    New York         UP_LOW
1 2021-02-06 18:48:18.097962  Berlin       Tokyo        DN_HIGH
2 2021-02-06 18:47:08.209495   Paris     Toronto       DROP_LOW
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `split` the issue column first, transform only the first part with the mapping and then add the remaining part back:

```
splits = df['issue'].str.split('_')
short_issue = splits.str[0].map(issue_short_form_map).fillna(splits.str[0])
df['issue'] = short_issue + '_' + splits.str[1]

df
#                        date  source destination     issue
#0 2021-02-06 18:48:18.097962  London    New York    UP_LOW
#1 2021-02-06 18:48:18.097962  Berlin       Tokyo   DN_HIGH
#2 2021-02-06 18:47:08.209495   Paris     Toronto  DROP_LOW
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

```
list_to_change = [i for i in issue_short_form_map.keys()]

def check_replace(x):
    """
    Check elements in x and compare to change

    """
    for element_to_check in list_to_change:
        if x.__contains__(element_to_check):
            return x.replace(element_to_check,issue_short_form_map[element_to_check])
    return x
df["issue"]= df["issue"].map(check_replace)
print(df)
                        date  source destination     issue
0 2021-02-06 18:48:18.097962  London    New York    UP_LOW
1 2021-02-06 18:48:18.097962  Berlin       Tokyo   DN_HIGH
2 2021-02-06 18:47:08.209495   Paris     Toronto  DROP_LOW
```

Answer (score 0):

the dictionary method get allows for a default value if a match is not found.  This resolves the case for the missing key/value pair match for drop.

```
   data = [(datetime(2021, 2, 6, 18, 48, 18, 97962), u'London', u'New York', u'UPLOAD_LOW'), (datetime(2021, 2, 6, 18, 48, 18, 97962), u'Berlin', u'Tokyo', u'DOWNLOAD_HIGH'), (datetime(2021, 2, 6, 18, 47, 8, 209495), u'Paris', u'Toronto', u'DROP_LOW')]
   df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['date','source','destination','issue']).reset_index().fillna(0)
   #print(df)
   issue_short_form_map = {
         "UPLOAD": "UP",
         "MEMORY": "MEM",
         "DOWNLOAD": "DN"
 }
 mylist=df['issue'].apply(lambda row: row.split("_"))
 mylist=[issue_short_form_map.get(x[0],x[0])+"_"+str(x[1]) for x in mylist]    
 df['issue']=mylist
 print(df)

 output:
    index                       date  source destination     issue
 0      0 2021-02-06 18:48:18.097962  London    New York    UP_LOW
 1      1 2021-02-06 18:48:18.097962  Berlin       Tokyo   DN_HIGH
 2      2 2021-02-06 18:47:08.209495   Paris     Toronto  DROP_LOW
```